# The usage of dot dot dot in writing

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it acceptable to have multiple dot in a speech when writing a composition to indicate the feeling of the person?

Example like when the person scared.

> The boy said, "My... fa...ther is... very angry!"

Comment: I would say the dots indicate hesitation . . . in . . . speech. Bold or capitals could express a **strong feeling**. Hyphenation could indicate slow -  and - deliberate - speech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the ellipsis (technical name for dot dot dot :-) is acceptable when used between words.

> The boy said, "My... father... is... very angry!"

It would [indicate halting speech](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/when-to-use-ellipses.html), either because the speaker is unsure about what they're saying, or because they are very upset and can't get the words out.

I've never seen it used between syllables like that. It's not even clear what a pause between syllables would mean since people would typically speak in whole words. However, if there was a break between syllables, I think a dash would be acceptable:

> He said "You are ab-so-lute-ly wrong!"

Comment: The referenced website, at least as it reads [as of now,](https://web.archive.org/web/20190416080324/https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/when-to-use-ellipses.html) does not say that an ellipsis "indicates halting speech". Even if it did, I'm not aware of any reason to take any opinions of that website or its publisher as authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

The use of three dots to indicate the hesitation in reported speech, or to indicate that words have been removed from a quotation, is called 'ellipsis'. Most people find it to be acceptable to use it as you have, but you may find some who object to ellipsis being used for any purpose other than to indicate that a quotation has been edited to make it shorter by removing some words from the original. This, possibly more typical use of ellipsis, can be seen in the following quotation from Oscar Wilde;

> A man's very highest moment is, I have no doubt at all, when he kneels in the dust, and beats his breast, and tells all the sins of his life.

This may be quoted using ellipsis to remove the words within commas:

> A man's very highest moment is ... when he kneels in the dust, and beats his breast, and tells all the sins of his life.

Some people do not like a space before or after the ellipsis, some prefer the exact opposite. Personally, I don't think it matters which you use, as long as you are consistent. If writing for a particular publication, or a particular publisher, they may have a house rule regarding how ellipsis should be used. In that case, always abide by their house rule.